# Auto select listbox items from searchbox

Tags: powershell, listbox, search-box

I cant seem to figure out how to auto select an item in my listbox from a searchbox.
I get a write-host back that an item is in the listbox when I use the searchbox, but I would like to autoselect the item that I search for.

The searchbox looks for the item that has the text in it from the searchbox. When you press the find button, the console says if the item is in the list or not.

I tried a couple of things with $objListbox.SelectedIndex, but I got as far as only selecting the first item in the listbox

```
#  Alle Variabelen
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

$reg_bestanden_dir = "\\dataasp01\d$\system\scripts\ADVIESBOX\adviesbox_update_release\Productie\"
#$Listtxt = "\\dataasp01\d$\system\scripts\ADVIESBOX\adviesbox_update_release\script\Test.txt"
$count=1#>
$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Find = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

$regbestanden= Get-ChildItem $reg_bestanden_dir | where {$_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'} |select name 



# Hoofd formulier
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>


[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Adviesbox Omgeving"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})


# Searchbox
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

$handler_Find_Click=
{

  Foreach ($regbestand in $regbestanden)
  {
        if($regbestand -match $textbox1.Text) 
        {

            #Select item in listbox

            Write-Host "Item is in the list"
        }

        else
        {
            Write-Host "Item is not the same"
        }
   }
}

#  Buttons
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

$StartenButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StartenButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,400)
$StartenButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$StartenButton.Text = "Starten"
$StartenButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem; Starten})
$objForm.Controls.Add($StartenButton)

$UpdateButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$UpdateButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,400)
$UpdateButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$UpdateButton.Text = "Update"
$UpdateButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;  Updaten})
$objForm.Controls.Add($UpdateButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(275,400)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# GUI boxen
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(190,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Selecteer een Adviesbox Omgeving:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 350

$countListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$countListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (200,18)
$countListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (30,25)
$objForm.Controls.Add($countListBox)

$textBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 250
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 15
$textBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$textBox1.Name = "textBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 120
$textBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$textBox1.TabIndex = 0
$objForm.Controls.Add($textBox1)

<# Autocomplete deels werkend
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = 'CustomSource'
$textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = 'SuggestAppend'
$textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = $autocomplete

Get-Content $Listtxt | % {$textbox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($_)}
#>

$Find.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 375
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 15
$Find.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Find.Name = "Find"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 50
$Find.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Find.TabIndex = 1
$Find.Text = "Find"
$Find.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Find.add_Click($handler_Find_Click)

$objForm.Controls.Add($Find)


# Functies
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

Function Starten
{
    Set-Location -Path $reg_bestanden_dir
    reg import $objListBox.SelectedItem
    #invoke-item $adviesb0x
}


Function Updaten
{
    Invoke-Item $objListBox.SelectedItem 
}

# Warning box voor de juiste omgeving
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

 <#$objListbox.add_SelectedIndexChanged(
     { 
          [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($objlistBox.SelectedItem, "Omgeving:")
     }
)#>

# Laat alle omgevingen zien in de listbox
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

<# foreach ($regbestand in $regbestanden) {
  $regbestand.name
}#>


$regbestanden | ForEach-Object {
 [void] $objListBox.Items.Add($_.name)
}

# Telt de aantal omgevingen (teller)
<#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>

$countListBox.Items.Add($regbestanden.count)




$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x



<#Backup#>

#https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx

#Get-Content $Listtxt | ForEach-Object {[void] $objListBox.Items.Add($_)}

#$objForm.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Minimized
  <#Set-Location -Path "\\dataasp01\d$\system\scripts\ADVIESBOX\adviesbox_update_release\Productie\"
        Write-Host "Item is in list"
        $findeditems = Get-ChildItem $objListBox.Items | where {$objListbox.Items -eq $textbox1.Text}
        $objListbox.Items.Add($findeditems)#>
```

Comment: Next time, please minimize your script to what is important this usually also results in a quicker answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$handler_Find_Click=
{
    Foreach ($regbestand in $regbestanden)
    {
        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $objListBox.Items.Count; $i++) {
            if($regbestand -match $objListBox.Items[$i]) 
            {
                $objListBox.SetSelected($i, $True)
                Write-Host "Item is in the list"
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Item is not the same"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether you want multiple items selected in the ListBox (depending on the [SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)) but you might have to deselect them first:

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $objListBox.Items.Count; $i++) {
    $objListBox.SetSelected($i, $False)
}
```